# Is it always true that if the function is not continuous at a point, then it's not differentiable at this point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I have this in my HW.

> Is
>   $
> f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
>   5 - x^2, & x \leq -2 \\
>   4x + 7, & x > -2
> \end{cases}
> $

I believe it is not differentiable, because $x$ is not continuous at $x=-2$. Is it always true that if the function is not continuous at a point, then it's not differentiable at this point?

Comment: Yes. Differentiability (a ta point) implies continuity (at this point).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since a function differentiable at a point is continuous at this point.

Comment: (+1), because there's actually not more to say.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $x$. Then, by definition,
$$d := \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
exists (and is finite). This implies that, by limit being distributable over a product,
$$f(x+h)-f(x) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \cdot h \to d \cdot 0 = 0$$
i.e. $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember:

$f$ is differentiable at $x=a\implies f$ is continuous at $x=a$.

What is its **contrapositive**?